# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-fs0wmmw4/mysqlclient/

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu-16.04

When I type the following command in Ubuntu 16.04

```
$ pip install mysqlclient
```

I get the following error:

```
`enter code here`Collecting mysqlclient
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6f/86/bad31f1c1bb0cc99e88ca2adb7cb5c71f7a6540c1bb001480513de76a931/mysqlclient-1.3.12.tar.gz (89kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 136kB/s 
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    /bin/sh: 1: mysql_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-fs0wmmw4/mysqlclient/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        metadata, options = get_config()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-fs0wmmw4/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 44, in get_config
        libs = mysql_config("libs_r")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-fs0wmmw4/mysqlclient/setup_posix.py", line 26, in mysql_config
        raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-fs0wmmw4/mysqlclient/
```

Answer (score 20):

Try these instructions:

https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python

Or if you are using python 3. Go with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev

sudo pip3 install mysqlclient
```

They both worked in my case.

Hope!! this helps

Comment: Both executed for me too. I am using Python 3 with ubuntu 16.04. But still when I am trying to execute this with ipython notebook:

db_url = {
    'database': "city_details",
    'drivername': 'mysql',
    'username': 'root',
    'password': '......',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'query': {'charset': 'utf8'},  # the key-point setting
}

engine = create_engine(URL(**db_url), encoding="utf8")

I am getting this error:
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'

Comment: Try this once apt-get install python-mysqldb

Answer (score 4):

I have just faced with this problem on Debian 10:

According to github (https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient) now should use this:

If you are on # Debian / Ubuntu first run:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential
```

If you are on # Red Hat / CentOS first run:

```
sudo yum install python3-devel mysql-devel
```

Then you can install mysqlclient:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 1):

After some investigations, and trying different solutions, I found out some points as below:

1- Most of the users install the Python from apt-get on Ubuntu 16.04.

2- The version which is exist on the main Ubuntu repository, is 3.5.x. The `mysqlclient` that you install with `pip`, has problem with python3s whose version are under the v3.6. So you should install Python3.6.

3- If you are on Windows, you could use a compiled version of `mysqlclient` as wheel file. You could find some of wheel files, [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#mysqlclient). Just download the file, and then:

```
pip install "path-of-wheel-file"
```

4- If you are using Ubuntu, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/865554/how-do-i-install-python-3-6-using-apt-get), install the python3.6 via these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6 python3.6-dev libmysqlclient-dev libmysqld-dev unzip
```

5- You should update `setuptools`:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

for python3.6:

```
python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

6- At the last step, you should install mysqlclient from source:

```
wget https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip
cd mysqlclient-python-master
python setup.py install
```

If your are using Django 1.11 LTS version, you should clone an older mysqlclient version (ex: v1.3.13):

```
wget https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient-python/archive/1.3.13.zip
unzip 1.3.13.zip
cd mysqlclient-python-master
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Taking up [this valuable comment from the most voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9255271/priyanka-jain),

```
apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

solves this.

For instance, in a Dockerfile, it would look like:

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip libmysqlclient-dev python-dev python-mysqldb
```