# Python package installation error on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, pip, virtual-machine

I have installed python 2.7 in addition to an existing python3 on Ubuntu virtual machine. When I tried to install package `pycbc` with `python -m pip install pycbc`, it gone to error : (I have checked that `python` is of version python 2.7.17)

```
Collecting pycbc
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/56/198e305382d374f0654cd38c4f302919514ba646e42c44dc5e9280f85227/PyCBC-1.16.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:1657 kmod_module_new_from_loaded: could not open /proc/modules: No such file or directory
    Error: could not get list of modules: No such file or directory
    /usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/extension.py:133: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'compiler_directives'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-DXkpBU/pycbc/setup.py", line 297, in <module>
        'License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)',
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 128, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 123, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 513, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 774, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1057, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1069, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 580, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 698, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 724, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 909, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1177, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1163, in run_setup
        run_setup(setup_script, args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 253, in run_setup
        raise
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 35, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 166, in save_modules
        saved_exc.resume()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 141, in resume
        six.reraise(type, exc, self._tb)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
        yield saved
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
        yield
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
        _execfile(setup_script, ns)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 44, in _execfile
        code = compile(script, filename, 'exec')
      File "/tmp/easy_install-ewF3Uk/numpy-1.19.0rc1/setup.py", line 182
        raise ValueError(f'Submodule {p} missing')
                                                ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-DXkpBU/pycbc/
```

Comment: The numpy setup line indicates this is a NumPy version that only supports Python 3(.6 and later). Wheter this is due to an incorrect dependency settings (on NumPy) in `pycbc`, I can't tell.

Comment: The odd thing is that [`install_requires` in `setup.py` on the GitHub repository](https://github.com/gwastro/pycbc/blob/master/setup.py), shows the following two lines: `'numpy>=1.16.0; python_version >= "3.5"', 'numpy>=1.16.0,<1.17.0; python_version <= "2.7"',`. So I'm not sure why your traceback is showing NumPy version 1.19.0rc1.

Comment: It's strange. The pycbc should supports python2 only and python3 support is under developement.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be true. The travis build is passing, and travis is run only for Python 3.6 (as Python 2.7 is now phased out). PyPI also lists both Python 2.7 and Python 3.6.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49862527/command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1-in-tmp-pip-install

Comment: lol. It was due to the old version of pip (it was version of 9.xx). After updating, I could install the package. However, some of the modules are missing and I am dealing with that. Anyway, thanks for the suggestions.